# Loop through files with specific extensions (not all extensions might exist)

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

I have the following simple script to loop through files with specific extensions and generate an XML file with the parsed file names without extensions.  However, if any of the extensions does not exist in the directory, it results in *.ext and messes up the results.  How do I ensure that it only grabs names of the real files and not something like *.wlens?

P.S. I'm doing the more complex name parsing (sed) because files might contain "." in the name.  If there are more efficient ways of doing that, I would appreciate your input.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
    " > retrieve_xmd_build_package.xml

for i in *.{wdash,wcomp,wlens};
do
   
    echo "<members>" >> retrieve_xmd_build_package.xml 
    echo "    " "$i"| sed 's#^\(.*\)\.\(.*\)#\1#'     >> retrieve_xmd_build_package.xml 
    echo "</members>" >> retrieve_xmd_build_package.xml 
done

echo "<name>WaveXMD</name>" >> retrieve_xmd_build_package.xml 
echo "

   </types>

   <version>56.0</version>

</Package>

" >> retrieve_xmd_build_package.xml
```

Here is the result with an incorrect entry for one of the extensions:

```
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?>

<Package xmlns=http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata>
    <types>
    
<members>
     weekday DASH
</members>
<members>
     *
</members>
<members>
     weekday LENS 2
</members>
<members>
     weekday LENS
</members>
<name>WaveXMD</name>


   </types>

   <version>56.0</version>

</Package>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd be inclined to use `find`, but you could do this in bash by setting the `nullglob` option.  i.e. somewhere before your `for` loop, add:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

From `man bash`:

> `nullglob`
>
> If set, bash allows patterns which match no files (see Pathname Expansion  above)  to  expand  to  a  null
> string, rather than themselves.

For example, compare the difference with `nullglob` set and unset.  First, unset (which is normally the default unless you set it in .bashrc or other profile script):

```
$ shopt -u nullglob
$ for i in *.{wdash,wcomp,wlens}; do echo "$i"; done
*.wdash
*.wcomp
*.wlens
```

None of those file globs exist in the current directory, so with `nullglob` unset, bash expands the unmatched globs to themselves (i.e. just uses the globs as literal strings)

Next with nullglob set:

```
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ for i in *.{wdash,wcomp,wlens}; do echo "$i"; done
```

i.e. the for loop doesn't print anything because the nullglob setting prevents an unmatched glob from expanding to itself.

Beware that in bash, the `failglob` option takes precedence over `nullglob`. So if `failglob` is set, `nullglob` has no effect. If `failglob` might be set, you'd need to unset it with `shopt -u failglob` in order to be able to use `nullglob`.